# Ergodicity and dense orbits

Tags: ergodic-theory, topological-dynamics

Consider a compact separable Hausdorff space $X$ endowed with a finite
Radon measure $\mu$ of full support and a continuous measure-preserving
ergodic transformation $T$. Is there a dense orbit for the transformation?

Recall that a topological space is separable if it admits a dense countable subset. It is second countable if there is a countable family of open sets such that any open sets is the union of members of this family.
A Hausdorff compact space is metrizable if and only if it is second countable.

The result is well known if the space is second countable (or metrizable). 
An example of compact group that is separable but not second countable
is given by a product of uncountably (cardinal of the continuum) many
circles. It is easily checked that ergodic translations on such a group
have a dense orbit.

Comment: are you assuming $\mu$ is Borel?

Comment: Yes. Radon means Borel together with inner regularity.

Comment: So why can't you take the usual construction of $T$-generic points (due to Furstenberg)? Uryshon's lemma will give you countably-many functions on $C(X)$ through which you can deduce that the orbit closure of a generic point contains each pt from the dense subset, and hence the orbit closure is the whole space.

Comment: @Asaf I think that you need second countability to use this approach. Separability is not enough.

Comment: Oh I see, $C(X)$ is separable means that $X$ is metrizable.

Comment: Regarding the example of rotations of topological groups. Can you extend the argument from metric spaces to uniform spaces?

Comment: The argument showing that ergodicity is equivalent to the existence of a dense orbit for translations of compact groups uses harmonic analysis (Peter-Weyl theorem) which ultimately relies on the Stone-Weierstrass theorem (no need for second countability here). If  a group is not dense, then there is a non-trivial character on the group that vanishes on the orbit and this gives a non-constant invariant function. A compact Hausdorff space is indeed uniformizable, but I am not sure if that helps.

Comment: I guess this can be proved by the following steps. First since $\mu$ is ergodic and of full support then $(X,T)$ is topologically transitive. Second a compact Hausdorff space is of second category. Last in $X$ is separable and of second category, if $(X,T)$ is topologically transitive, then it is point transitive, which means there is a dense orbit.

Comment: @Tu What do you mean by "second category"? My question is about compact spaces that are not second countable (equivalently, not metrizable). The result is well known for second countable compact spaces and I think that you are describing the proof in that setting.

Comment: It is true that for any countable family of measurable sets of positive measure, almost every $x\in X$ visits infinitely many times each set of the family. But, again, not having a countable basis makes it difficult to proceed.

Comment: @coudy  A set is called to be of second category if it is not a union of countably many nowhere dense subsets.

Comment: I have a proof assuming first countability. Using local countable basis sets at each point of the dense subset, one can use Urysohn's lemma in order to extract countably many "$\delta$-approximations", and using a generic-point construction for this particular set of functions, get existence of dense orbits. I don't know how to solve the general case.

Comment: @Asaf Indeed, separability + first countability is enough. Note that for a compact group, first countability implies second countability (Birkhoff Kakutani). To my surprise, there exist compact, first countable, separable spaces that are not second countable, e.g. the Helly space. So this is an improvement over second countability.

Comment: @coudy , Now I am actually starting to think that this assertion is false, if the space is not first-countable (or some closely related notion, like existence local-countable sub-basis for a separable set), there is some "density point" from the dense subset,with uncountable local basis, and by cardinality argument, no (countable)-orbit may visit all of those open nbhds, but one should be a bit careful here (as those nbhds might be contained one in another, but probably some clever Urysohn argument/compactness argument) should construct uncountably many nbhds which form a monotone family.